# Only the first answer of an array of objects returning true in a trivia game, rather than the correct answer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, object

I am building a trivia game that has four answer buttons. This array of objects is returning true only when the first answer (index 0) is clicked, even when it is false. I think the  "answer" might be bugged somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. "answer" and "randomQuestion" are global variables. What am I missing here?

```
question: '10 + 5 equals:',
        answers: [
          { text: '5', correct: false },
          { text: '10', correct: false },
          { text: '20', correct: false },
          { text: '15', correct: true }
        ]
      }
```

```
function nextQuestion() {
  nextButton.classList.add('hide');
  randomQuestion = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)];
  questionText.textContent = randomQuestion.question;
  randomQuestion.answers.forEach((answer, index) => {
    document.getElementById(`answers-btn-${index + 1}`).textContent = answer.text;
    result.textContent = "";
  });
}
```

```
function checkAnswer(bntIndex) {
  nextButton.classList.remove('hide');
  const currentQuestion = 0;
  answer = questions[currentQuestion].answers[bntIndex];
  if(answer.correct === true) {
    incrementPoints();
    result.textContent = "Correct!";
  } else {
    result.textContent = "Incorrect";
  }
}
```

```
<button id="answers-btn-1" onclick="checkAnswer(0)" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-2" onclick="checkAnswer(1)" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-3" onclick="checkAnswer(2)" class="answers-btn"></button>
<button id="answers-btn-4" onclick="checkAnswer(3)" class="answers-btn"></button>
```

Comment: One observation is **const currentQuestion = 0;** in **checkAnswer** will always reference the first question in the array no matter what is being displayed. Probably should be **randomQuestion**?

Comment: Thank you. I tried that however it did not work. I think that is close to working somehow though

Comment: question: '10 + 5 equals:', doesn't make any sense.  Did you mean let questions = {..., also nextbutton is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I removed `const currentQuestion = 0` and changed to this `answer = randomQuestion.answers[bntIndex];` and it works.